# Python: Recursive pass by value, 4 queens

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a backtracking algorithm, in Python, to solve the 4 queens problem. I have created a class Queens with the following:

```
def __init__(self, board_size=4):
    self.board  = [[0 for i in xrange(0,board_size)] for i in xrange(0,board_size)];
```

But when I implement the recursive backtrack, due to pass by reference the board gets filled with 1s everywhere that has been visited.

```
def backtrack(self, board, next_column):
            (algorithm here) ...
            board[i][column] = 1 ... #to indicate a placed queen
            self.backtrack(board, next_column + 1);
            (rest of algorithm)
```

I know that I can do

```
new_board = copy.deepcopy(board);
```

Shallow copies wont work for higher dimensional arrays. 
Is there a better way of doing this, since I hear there are some problems with deepcopy?
Answers which suggest a different data structure other than a 2d list is also acceptable.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with deepcopy, really, except that it can be pretty slow sometimes.  In this case, that might not be an issue anyway.  But there are several alternatives.

If you want to stick with lists, you could simply make a one-deep copy:

```
In [63]: n = 8

In [64]: board  = [[0 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

In [65]: timeit board2 = [r[:] for r in board]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.24 us per loop

In [66]: timeit board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.8 us per loop
```

Note that the deepcopy is slow.

[Side note: Actually, this is my favourite (non-numpy) idiom for making a 2D-array:

```
In [69]: board = [x[:] for x in [[0]*n]*n]
```

but lots of people don't like it because it's too close to things which are wrong, even though it works by itself, and in that sense isn't very robust.]

But maybe a better approach is to use a dictionary instead:

```
In [79]: board = {(i,j): 0 for i in range(n) for j in range(n)}

In [80]: timeit board2 = board.copy()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.46 us per loop
```